# Creating a custom made "du" in C

Tags: c, linux

for the past weeks i've been working on creating a program that should work like the 'du' command on linux with these flags:
`du -l -s -B512`

I've managed to get the general of the program to work on smaller files but when it get's tested it for some reason fails a test on a large directory using 1 thread and I cannot figure it out.

Using 1 argument `/usr/lib`, I get this output:

```
7436496 /usr/lib
```

whereas I expected this:

```
7437280 /usr/lib
```

I have tried debugging and recreating this error by running tests on my machine but I always get the same results as the 'du' command as seen here:

```
$ ./mdu -j1
704664  lib
```

vs:

```
$ du -s -1
704664  lib
```

Code in **mdu.c**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include "queue.h"
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/statvfs.h> 

void parse_options(int argc, char** argv, int* jflag, int* num_threads, char*** files, int* num_files);
int list_files(const char* path, size_t* totalSize);
void* thread_function(void* arg);
int process_directory(const char* path, size_t* totalSize, pthread_mutex_t* sizeMutex, Queue* workQueue);
int process_directory_queue(const char* path, size_t* totalSize);
int accumulate_file_size(const char* path, size_t* totalSize);
int handle_directory_entry(const char* path, const struct dirent* entry, size_t* totalSize, pthread_mutex_t* sizeMutex, Queue* workQueue);
int add_directory_size(const char* path, size_t* totalSize, pthread_mutex_t* sizeMutex);
int handle_subdirectory(const char* nextPath, size_t* totalSize, pthread_mutex_t* sizeMutex, Queue* workQueue);
int handle_regular_file(const struct stat* st, size_t* totalSize, pthread_mutex_t* sizeMutex);

typedef struct ThreadData {
    Queue* workQueue;
    pthread_mutex_t* sizeMutex;
    size_t* totalSize;
} ThreadData;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int jflag = 0;
    int num_threads = 1;
    char** files;
    int num_files;
    ThreadData data;
    Queue workQueue;
    int error_occurred = 0;

    parse_options(argc, argv, &jflag, &num_threads, &files, &num_files);

    pthread_mutex_t sizeMutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
    data.sizeMutex = &sizeMutex;
    data.workQueue = &workQueue;
    initialize_queue(&workQueue);

    for (int i = 0; i < num_files; i++) {
        size_t totalsize = 0;  
        data.totalSize = &totalsize;
        enqueue_item(&workQueue, files[i]);

        if (jflag == 0 || num_threads == 1) {
            error_occurred |= list_files(files[i], &totalsize);  
        } else {
            pthread_t threads[num_threads];
            int ret;
            for (int j = 0; j < num_threads; ++j) {
                ret = pthread_create(&threads[j], NULL, thread_function, &data);
                if (ret != 0) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "Error: Cannot create thread %d\n", j);
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }
            }

            for (int j = 0; j < num_threads; ++j) {
                ret = pthread_join(threads[j], NULL);
                if (ret != 0) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "Error: Cannot join thread %d\n", j);
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }
            }
        }

        printf("%ld\t%s\n", totalsize/2, files[i]); 
    }

    cleanup_queue(&workQueue);
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&sizeMutex);

    if (error_occurred) {
        return 1;  
    }
    return 0;
}

int list_files(const char* path, size_t* totalSize) {
    struct stat st;
    if (lstat(path, &st) == 0) {
        if (S_ISDIR(st.st_mode)) {
            return process_directory_queue(path, totalSize);
        } else if (S_ISREG(st.st_mode)) {
            return accumulate_file_size(path, totalSize);
        } else {
            fprintf(stderr, "Unsupported file type: %s\n", path);
            return 1;
        }
    } else {
        perror("lstat");
        return 1;
    }
}

int process_directory_queue(const char* path, size_t* totalSize) {
    pthread_mutex_t fakeMutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
    Queue fakeQueue;
    initialize_queue(&fakeQueue);
    enqueue_item(&fakeQueue, path);

    char nextPath[4096];
    while (true) {
        bool dequeued = dequeue_item(&fakeQueue, nextPath);
        if (!dequeued) {
            break;
        }
        int error = process_directory(nextPath, totalSize, &fakeMutex, &fakeQueue);
        if (error) {
            cleanup_queue(&fakeQueue);
            pthread_mutex_destroy(&fakeMutex);
            return error;
        }
    }

    cleanup_queue(&fakeQueue);
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&fakeMutex);
    return 0;
}

int accumulate_file_size(const char* path, size_t* totalSize) {
    struct stat st;
    if (lstat(path, &st) == 0) {
        unsigned long file_blocks = st.st_blocks;
        *totalSize += file_blocks;
        return 0;
    } else {
        perror("lstat file");
        return 1;
    }
}

void* thread_function(void* arg)
{
    ThreadData* data = (ThreadData*)arg;
    Queue* workQueue = data->workQueue;
    pthread_mutex_t* sizeMutex = data->sizeMutex;
    size_t* totalSize = data->totalSize;

    char path[4096];
    while (true) {
        bool success = dequeue_item(workQueue, path);
        if (!success) {
            break;
        }
        process_directory(path, totalSize, sizeMutex, workQueue);
    }

    return NULL;
}

int process_directory(const char* path, size_t* totalSize, pthread_mutex_t* sizeMutex, Queue* workQueue) {
    int error_occurred = 0;
    DIR* dp = opendir(path);
    if (dp == NULL) {
        perror("Unable to open directory");
        return 1;
    }

    struct dirent* entry;
    while ((entry = readdir(dp)) != NULL) {
        if (handle_directory_entry(path, entry, totalSize, sizeMutex, workQueue) != 0) {
            error_occurred = 1;
        }
    }

    if (add_directory_size(path, totalSize, sizeMutex) != 0) {
        error_occurred = 1;
    }

    closedir(dp);
    return error_occurred;
}

int handle_directory_entry(const char* path, const struct dirent* entry, size_t* totalSize, pthread_mutex_t* sizeMutex, Queue* workQueue) {
    if (strcmp(entry->d_name, ".") == 0 || strcmp(entry->d_name, "..") == 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    char nextPath[4096];
    snprintf(nextPath, sizeof(nextPath), "%s/%s", path, entry->d_name);

    struct stat st;
    if (lstat(nextPath, &st) == 0) {
        if (S_ISDIR(st.st_mode)) {
            return handle_subdirectory(nextPath, totalSize, sizeMutex, workQueue);
        } else if (S_ISREG(st.st_mode)) {
            return handle_regular_file(&st, totalSize, sizeMutex);
        }
    } else {
        if (errno == EACCES) {
            fprintf(stderr, "du: cannot read directory '%s': Permission denied\n", nextPath);
            return 1;
        } else {
            perror("lstat");
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int handle_subdirectory(const char* nextPath, size_t* totalSize, pthread_mutex_t* sizeMutex, Queue* workQueue) {
    DIR* sub_dp = opendir(nextPath);
    if (sub_dp == NULL) {
        if (errno == EACCES) {
            fprintf(stderr, "du: cannot read directory '%s': Permission denied\n", nextPath);
            add_directory_size(nextPath, totalSize, sizeMutex); // Add the size even if access is denied.
            return 1; // Error occurred
        } else {
            perror("Unable to open sub-directory");
            return 1; // Error occurred
        }
    } else {
        closedir(sub_dp);  
        enqueue_item(workQueue, nextPath);
        return 0; // Success
    }
}

int handle_regular_file(const struct stat* st, size_t* totalSize, pthread_mutex_t* sizeMutex) {
    unsigned long file_blocks = st->st_blocks;
    pthread_mutex_lock(sizeMutex);
    *totalSize += file_blocks;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(sizeMutex);
    return 0; // Success
}

int add_directory_size(const char* path, size_t* totalSize, pthread_mutex_t* sizeMutex) {
    struct stat st_dir;
    if (lstat(path, &st_dir) == 0) {
        unsigned long dir_blocks = st_dir.st_blocks;
        pthread_mutex_lock(sizeMutex);
        *totalSize += dir_blocks;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(sizeMutex);
        return 0; // Success
    } else {
        perror("lstat directory");
        return 1; // Error occurred
    }
}

void parse_options(int argc, char** argv, int* jflag, int* num_threads, char*** files, int* num_files) {
    int c;
    while ((c = getopt(argc, argv, "j:")) != -1) {
        switch (c) {
        case 'j':
            *jflag = 1;
            *num_threads = atoi(optarg);
            if (*num_threads <= 0) {
                fprintf(stderr, "-j has to be positive.\n");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            break;
        case '?':
            if (isprint(optopt)) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Unknown option '-%c'.\n", optopt);
            }
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        default:
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    *num_files = argc - optind;
    *files = argv + optind;
}
```

This is the **queue.c**:

```
#include "queue.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void initialize_queue(Queue* queue) 
{
    queue->head = NULL;
    queue->tail = NULL;
    pthread_mutex_init(&(queue->mutex), NULL);
    pthread_cond_init(&(queue->cond_var), NULL);
}

void enqueue_item(Queue* queue, const char* path) 
{
    Item* item = (Item*) malloc(sizeof(Item));

    if (item == NULL) {
        perror("Malloc Error: ");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    strncpy(item->path, path, sizeof(item->path) - 1);
    item->next = NULL;

    pthread_mutex_lock(&(queue->mutex));
    if (queue->tail == NULL) {
        queue->head = item;
        queue->tail = item;
    } else {
        queue->tail->next = item;
        queue->tail = item;
    }
    pthread_cond_signal(&(queue->cond_var));
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&(queue->mutex));
}

bool dequeue_item(Queue* queue, char* path) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&(queue->mutex));
    if (queue->head == NULL) {
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&(queue->mutex));
        return false;  
    }
    Item* item = queue->head;
    queue->head = item->next;
    if (queue->head == NULL) {
        queue->tail = NULL;
    }
    strncpy(path, item->path, 4096);
    free(item);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&(queue->mutex));
    return true;
}

void cleanup_queue(Queue* queue) {
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&(queue->mutex));
    pthread_cond_destroy(&(queue->cond_var));
    while (queue->head != NULL) {
        Item* item = queue->head;
        queue->head = item->next;
        free(item);
    }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated thanks.

**EDIT:**  **queue.h**:

```
#ifndef QUEUE_H
#define QUEUE_H

#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

typedef struct Item {
    char path[4096];
    struct Item* next;
} Item;

typedef struct Queue {
    Item* head;
    Item* tail;
    pthread_mutex_t mutex;
    pthread_cond_t cond_var;
} Queue;

void initialize_queue(Queue* queue);
void enqueue_item(Queue* queue, const char* path);
bool dequeue_item(Queue* queue, char* path);
void cleanup_queue(Queue* queue);

#endif // QUEUE_H
```

**EDIT 2**:

This is the feedback I have gotten:

busy-waiting on in the `while` `true` loop, a condition variable is required.

Could this cause this issue?

**EDIT 3**

After suspecting the symbolic links were the issue these functions were changed/implemented to handle them:

```
int handle_symbolic_link(const char* path, ThreadData* data) {
    struct stat st;
    if (lstat(path, &st) == 0) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(data->sizeMutex);
        *(data->totalSize) += st.st_size;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(data->sizeMutex);
        return 0;
    } else {
        perror("lstat symbolic link");
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Change in `handle_directory_entry`

```
int handle_directory_entry(const char* path, const struct dirent* entry, ThreadData* data) {
    if (strcmp(entry->d_name, ".") == 0 || strcmp(entry->d_name, "..") == 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    char nextPath[4096];
    snprintf(nextPath, sizeof(nextPath), "%s/%s", path, entry->d_name);

    struct stat st;
    if (lstat(nextPath, &st) == 0) {
        if (S_ISDIR(st.st_mode)) {
            return handle_subdirectory(nextPath, data);
        }
        else if (S_ISREG(st.st_mode)) {
            return handle_regular_file(&st, data);
        }
        else if (S_ISLNK(st.st_mode)) {
            return handle_symbolic_link(nextPath,data);
        }
    }
    else {
        if (errno == EACCES) {
            fprintf(stderr, "du: cannot read directory '%s': Permission denied\n", nextPath);
            return 1;
        }
        else {
            perror("lstat");
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

After testing these are the new reports:

```
7475809 /usr/lib
```

whereas I expected this:

```
7437280 /usr/lib
```

I am also failing this tests the explicitly checks for symbolic link as seen here

```
TEST - Symbolic link [FAILED]
Check that the program does not follow symbolic links: ./mdu a

mkdir a
fallocate -l 65537 a/a
ln -s ../b a/b
mkdir b
fallocate -l 94847 b/a
fallocate -l 6701 b/b

Program output:

156    a

Expected output:

152    a
```

This leads me to believe that either I am not supposed to handle symbolic links or the issue lies within hard links.

Comment: Test your program without threads. Test it on subdirectories of that `lib` directory. Make a copy of the `lib` directory and move files in and out of it to find the smallest set of files that produces an error. Reduce the problem to a [mre].

Comment: Minor: note `.st_blocks` is a signed type.

Comment: Not likely the issue, yet `strncpy(item->path, path, sizeof(item->path) - 1);` does not certainly _null character_ terminate `item->path` for long paths.  Likewise for `strncpy(path, item->path, 4096);`.  Consider `snprintf(dest, sizeof dest, "%s", src);`.  (IMO, code should exit if buff is not long enough.)

Comment: @Sp1tNMyFace – Once you write _when it get's tested it for some reason fails a test on a large directory_, then you write _I always get the same results as the 'du' command_; how does this go together?

Comment: _"Expected results are posted as pictures"_ - but **why**? They're both just text

Comment: @Armali I'm sorry let me clarify. The testing you see in the first picture is a testing done automatically when I hand the files in for testing. To be clear I don't have access to the usr/lib in the first picture since the testing is done automatically on my schools platform.

And in the second picture, I have tried to run the same command on the same file BUT on my system which is why I get two different numbers for usr/lib since I am guessing that the school usr/lib contains more files maybe for the purpose of testing.

Answer (score 1):

`/usr/lib` contains many symbolic links, such as:

```
libbfd-2.25-system.so
libbind9.so.90@
libbind9.so.90.0.9
libcdt.so.5@
libcdt.so.5.0.0
libcgraph.so.6@
libcgraph.so.6.0.0
libdiscover.so.2@
libdiscover.so.2.0.1
libdns.so.100@
libdns.so.100.2.2
```

for which you should accumulate the size as they are not necessarily stored inside the inode.

Another more difficult problem is the **du** command only counts files and directories once even in presence of multiple hard links pointing to the same inode.  For example, on my macOS laptop, the subdirectory `/usr/lib/usd/usd/usdShaders/resources/shaders` has this contents:

```
$ ls -lis /usr/lib/usd/usd/usdShaders/resources/shaders
total 48
1152921500312436903 16 -rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  14922 May 13 00:29 previewSurface.glslfx
1152921500312277175  8 -rw-r--r--  6 root  wheel   1223 May 13 00:29 primvarReader.glslfx
1152921500312436906  8 -rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  13867 May 13 00:29 shaderDefs.usda
1152921500312277250  8 -rw-r--r--  2 root  wheel   1223 May 13 00:29 transform2d.glslfx
1152921500312277175  8 -rw-r--r--  6 root  wheel   1223 May 13 00:29 uvTexture.glslfx
```

So `primvarReader.glslfx` and `uvTexture.glslfx` point to the same inode (which has 4 other paths pointing to it), and **du** only counts it once:

```
$ du -a /usr/lib/usd/usd/usdShaders/resources/shaders
16      /usr/lib/usd/usd/usdShaders/resources/shaders/previewSurface.glslfx
8       /usr/lib/usd/usd/usdShaders/resources/shaders/primvarReader.glslfx
8       /usr/lib/usd/usd/usdShaders/resources/shaders/shaderDefs.usda
8       /usr/lib/usd/usd/usdShaders/resources/shaders/transform2d.glslfx
40      /usr/lib/usd/usd/usdShaders/resources/shaders
```

Comment: Is it possible to achieve this behavior?
I'm thinking of using something like: 

`else if (S_ISLNK(st.st_mode)) {//Handle Links}`
in list_files to handle the symbolic links. I'm not quite sure what to do about the hard links.

Comment: I'd first handle the simpler case of symbolic links and test that; if you're lucky, you'll get by with that.

Comment: For the symbolic links you should just accumulate the nb of blocks for these entries too, and for the hard links, you can keep a list of inodes for the entries with a number of links > 1 for files and > 2 for directories and skip those that you have seen already.

Comment: Please check out EDIT 3 @chqrlie

Comment: @Sp1tNMyFace: how do you produce the *expected output*? `du a` outputs `72` on my linux server, which is consistent with `a/a` using 17 4k blocks, the `a/b` symbolic link entirely stored in its inode and the directory `a` itself a single 4k-block.

Comment: @chqrlie The expected output isn't produced by me but it its produced by the testing platform when i send in my .c files. It goes through tests like the one I have posted about at the end in which it fails. I do not have access to it so it's hard to see why it is going wrong.

Comment: Something I forgot to mention was the flags with du that my program should mimic: `du-s -l -B512 {file} [files ...]` 
The interesting one here is `-l, --count-links - count sizes many times if hard linked` Which tells me that I can handle hard links similarly to how I handled the other stuff? I.e not worry about inodes?

Comment: I think hard linkes are handled in `S_ISREG` which still leaves me with the initial issue of my program reporting less than expected.

Comment: @Sp1tNMyFace: you should edit the question and specify the `du` flags you emulate. `-l` definitely means you don't have to worry about the hard links.

Comment: @chqrlie Yeah sorry about that, should have been there from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>     if (lstat(nextPath, &st) == 0) {
>         if (S_ISDIR(st.st_mode)) {
>             return handle_subdirectory(nextPath, totalSize, sizeMutex, workQueue);
>         } else if (S_ISREG(st.st_mode)) {
>             return handle_regular_file(&st, totalSize, sizeMutex);
>         }
>     } …
> ```

Here your 'mdu' doesn't handle any file type other than directory or regular file, especially not symbolic link, which may also use data blocks.

Comment: It _should_ be logging `Unsupported file type` in that case though, and I don't _think_ it is, although of course it's impossible to be certain since OP only included a screenshot of a summary of the output, instead of the original text.

Comment: @Armali During the testing there is a specific test that checks for the Symbolic link, I will add a screenshot of that test as well [Here is a picture of the Symbolic link test.](https://imgur.com/a/1i9RDzr). Does this infer that the issue does not lie in symbolic links?

Comment: Added an EDIT 2 which is feedback I have gotten.

Comment: @Useless Are you referring to when I'm running `du -s -l` ?

Comment: @Armali: symbolic links may be to blame, but hard links pose problems too: `du` detects and removes duplicate names to the same inode.

Comment: @Useless – The logging `Unsupported file type` occurs only in the function `list_files`, and this function is only called for command line arguments; for files within directories the function `handle_directory_entry` is called, and from the cited snippet it's obvious that no error is printed in that case.

Comment: @Sp1tNMyFace – 
The above also anwers your question _Does this infer that the issue does not lie in symbolic links?_, i. e. _No, it doesn't_.